# Yahoo - caffe on Spark library dependency?

Tags: apache-spark, caffe-on-spark

Yahoo just released a version of caffe that uses the latest version of Apache-Spark yesterday, the git repo is not well documented yet: [git link](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark)

There is a scala test file which is suppose to run an example: [Scala Example](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/blob/master/caffe-grid/src/main/scala/com/yahoo/ml/caffe/examples/MyMLPipeline.scala)

but it requires the dependency com.yahoo.ml.caffe.{Config, CaffeOnSpark, DataSource} which I assume contains basically the data, the config and the API. Has this been made into a library yet? How could I build this using sbt?

Comment: Have you checked the [CaffeOnSpark wiki](https://github.com/yahoo/CaffeOnSpark/wiki) ?

Comment: @eliasah yes, I checked all the documents, the API document seems to suggest that they've already built the library, but maybe it is a local one packaged into the git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Our CaffeOnSpark release contains all the code that you need to run. com.yahoo.ml.caffe.* are collection of Scala classes in caffe-grid folder. Please follow our guides at CaffeOnSpark wiki page, and ask questions at your mailing list.